# Devise won't call custom failure on session controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, devise

I have the following custom session controller:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    respond_to :json

 def create
    logger.debug(" CUSTOM AUTHENTICATION!!!!!!")
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    render json: { :success => true }, status: 200
  end

  def failure
    logger.debug(" CUSTOM FAILURE!!!!!!")
    warden.custom_failure!
    render json: { success: false, errors: ["Login Credentials Failed"] }, status: 401
  end

end
```

I'm calling trough Ajax, and I need this success parameter in order to handle the callback.

Authentication is working fine. I'm receiving the `success: true` as response

But when authentication fails, I'm getting the default response:

```
"NetworkError: 401 Unauthorized - http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in.json"

Parameters:
  {"error":"Invalid e-mail or password"}
```

What am I missing there? Why devise won't call my custom failure message?

I have configured the devise.rb config:

```
config.navigational_formats = ["*/*", :html, :json]
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Can you post your controller code?

Comment: Nope. I had posted this in thedevise github issues page: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3142

Answer (score 0):

You are patching the SessionsController of Devise - this controller has no *failure* method in the SessionsController as you can see [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb). The 401 is being generated by the *new* method. However, instead of patching that method, I would use an after_filter like this:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  after_filter :handle_failed_login, :only => :new

  private
  def handle_failed_login
    if failed_login?
      render json: { success: false, errors: ["Login Credentials Failed"] }, status: 401
    end
  end 

  def failed_login?
    (options = env["warden.options"]) && options[:action] == "unauthenticated"
  end 
end
```

Comment: You're right saying that `session controller` has no `failure` method. But, `warde.authenticate` method, has this `recall` parameter in which you point the failure method, as you can see here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/failure_app.rb#L33 , and I'm doing that

Comment: There is a recall parameter for warden. But that has nothing to do with the sessions controller. You need to declare it like [this](http://pastie.org/9467965). Code taken from the original issue when this feature was implemented: https://github.com/hassox/warden/issues/73

Comment: The recall parameter has nothing to do with SessionsController, but the default failure_app of devise uses it (in the line I sent you). I'm not questioning your answer, I just don't feel it's the only way. 

I saw a lot of examples using the recall parameter in the sessions controller.

Comment: Very well, then you are not interested in *a* solution, but a specific solution tied to a specific implementation idea. Good hunting(;

Comment: This is the original SessionsController of Devise: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/24327c7310097b42e594ecd88e25b6b114d51e1d/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L15 As you can see, it's original create method, uses the recall on warden. And it works. So If I'm overriding this method using almost the same code (which uses the recall method), why their code works and mine not. I want to make sure this is not a bug. I do seek a solution and I'm thankful for your help, but also I need to know why this is not working when it should.

Comment: I've created a initializer "warde.rb", pasted the code you pointed in pastebin.

Also created handle_failed_login and failed_login? methods along with the after_filter configuration. Restarted the server. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to edit devise config and change config.navigational_formats
Then change path with :format => :json

### config/initializers/devise.rb

```
    config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :json]
```

### app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb

```
    api_v1_new_user_session_path(resource_name, :format => :json)
```

If You make this changes the :recall will be work